# Weird PM2 - NodeJS Version Behaviour

Tags: node.js, pm2, nvm

I am experiencing a weird bug with NodeJS's File System module, where the remove directory function is asking for a callback, despite there being one. Having a look, it turns out this is a bug with NodeJS that was resolved in later releases

I tried to update the server's nodeJS version, except, as NVM was reporting, it was already fully updated.

Using the `pm2 show APP_NAME` command, I determined that PM2 was running the app in NodeJS v10.19.0, and all steps to update it were fruitless.

So how can I fix this?

Notable Details:

- DigitalOcean Ubuntu 20 Droplet
- PM2 Installed
- NodeJS v16.15.1
- NVM Installed

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this issue, I had to kill the current in memory version of PM2, and go to the following directory as root:

`~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin` in there is a pm2 executable.

In order to get the application to run in Node v16.15.1, I had to run the following command `~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/pm2 start index.js --name APP_NAME`, and then and only then did it run the application properly.